# vue@3.2.47 vue-chartjs@5.2.0 objects as data

Tags: chart.js, vuejs3, vue-chartjs

I'm new to chartjs.
I want to ask is there an option to pass data as the documentation suggests?
like

```
  <Bar v-if="chartData !== null" :data="chartData" :options="options" />
....
ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend,BarController, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale)
....
    type: 'bar',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                data: [{ x: 'Sales', y: 20 }, { x: 'Revenue', y: 10 }]
            }]
        }
```

I get the error:

```
`[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of mounted hook 
  at <Anonymous ref=fn<reforwardRef> type="bar" data= 
Object { type: "bar", data: {…} }
  ... > 
  at <Anonymous key=0 data= 
Object { type: "bar", data: {…} }
 options= 
Object { scales: {…}, parsing: {…} }
 > 
  at <Graphs> 
  at <VMain> 
  at <VApp> 
  at <VLayout> 
  at <VCard> 
  at <App> 
  at <App>

Uncaught TypeError: nextDatasets is undefined
    setDatasets vue-chartjs.js:78
    cloneData vue-chartjs.js:96
    renderChart vue-chartjs.js:127
    createHook chunk-SE5EWVSA.js:3455
    callWithErrorHandling chunk-SE5EWVSA.js:1415
    callWithAsyncErrorHandling chunk-SE5EWVSA.js:1423
    __weh chunk-SE5EWVSA.js:3439
    flushPostFlushCbs chunk-SE5EWVSA.js:1570
    render2 chunk-SE5EWVSA.js:6141
    mount chunk-SE5EWVSA.js:4791
    mount chunk-SE5EWVSA.js:8688
    <anonymous> main.ts:23`
```

if so, what are the plugins required for that to work?

I tried to copy samples from the documentation because my implementation didn't work properly.